# ImportError al compilar model_builder_tf2_test.py al usar Object Detection API con TensorFlow2 y Python

Tags: python-3.7, tensorflow, cuda

Estoy configurando el entorno para realizar la detección de objetos utilizando TensorFlow2 y ObjectDetection siguiendo los pasos del siguiente recurso: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

Durante los pasos formulados se clona el repositorio, se compilan los archivos .proto, y al intentar realizar la compilación del archivo  python model_builder_tf2_test.py, para evaluar la correcta ejecución de los pasos, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
2020-09-30 11:07:31.921915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\anchor_generator_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\__init__.py)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El entorno que estoy trabajando esta compuesto por lo siguiente:

- CUDA 10.1
- Python 3.7.8
- TensorFlow 2.3.0

Librerias PIP relevantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos .py resultantes de compilar los protos, estan correctamente generados como se evidencia en la siguiente captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]